# C Socket Programming: Socket connects, but cannot write through socket to server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm working on a simple client/server implementation in which the client connects to the server based on the command line argument that specifies the hostname to search for a socket to connect with on (I just input localhost) and then sends a singular string that is reversed by the server, and then this reversed string is sent back to the client, and the reversed string prints. I am able to connect to the socket that lives at localhost (the client) but writing through the socket fails, and I am not sure why.

This is the server code: It has a built in reverser function that manually reverses a string and then writes it back through the socket to the client after reading in the original message that was written to the server by the client

```
#include <netdb.h>
#define BACKLOG 20
#include "server.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 200

char* reverse(char * word){
    char *reversed;
    int m=strlen(word);
    reversed=(char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * m));
    printf("%d",m);
    int i=0;
    while (i++!=m){
        char d= *(word+m-i);
        strncat(reversed,&d,1);
    }
    return reversed;
}

void reverser_response(int sockfd,char *write_buff,char *read_buff){
    read(sockfd,read_buff,sizeof(read_buff));
    char *reversed_message=reverse(read_buff);
    int i=0;
    while (*(reversed_message)!='\0'){
        write_buff[i]=*(reversed_message);
        i++;
        reversed_message=reversed_message+i;
    }
    write(sockfd,write_buff,sizeof(write_buff));
    bzero(write_buff,sizeof(write_buff));
    bzero(read_buff,sizeof(read_buff));
}



int main(){
    int cfd,afd;
    //I'm pretty sure service will be the port name
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];
    //hostname will be the name of the IP address
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char read_buff[200];
    char write_buff[200];
    //I rmemember hints is used to set certain settings within the struct addrinfo result we create
    struct addrinfo hints;
    //this is used for looping through possible addrinfo structus
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    //I think this stores the address of the client that connect with us
    struct sockaddr_storage claddr;
    //combined host + service name with padding of 10 bits
    char addrstr[NI_MAXHOST+NI_MAXSERV+10];
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    //socklen is the size of the socket
    socklen_t socklen;
    //I think AF_UNSPEC means that we can use an unspecified IP protocl: IPV4 or IPV6
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC; 
    //stream socket
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_next=NULL;
    hints.ai_canonname=NULL;
    hints.ai_addr=NULL;
    //Passive: we wait for someone to join with our socket, numeric serv: use the numeric host name
    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV;
    //getadrrinfo: 0 is success, takes in as arguments, NULL(?) our port number, references to the hints and result addrinfo structs
    //actually getaddrinfo generates a linked list of addrinfo structs for the specified host name/service name
    //in this case, result is the head of the linkedlist, hints is the hints thing that sets csome conditions
    if ((getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT_NUM,&hints,&result))!=0){
        printf("Failed to get result pointer of address structs");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //loop through possible addrinfo structs we can successfully create a socket at. Create socket at every possible struct. If we are successful
    //in binding then quit. bind takes as arguments the socket's file descriptor, the address of the socket, and the lenth of the socket's address
    //socket takes as arguments the addrinfo structu's ai_family (IPV4/6), socketpye (stream socket), and the protocol?
    for (rp=result;rp;rp!=NULL){
        cfd=socket(rp->ai_family,rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (cfd==-1){
            continue;
        }
        //rp->ai_addr could be a pointer to a sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6
        if (bind(cfd,rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen)==0){
            break;
        }
    } 
    if (rp==NULL){

        printf("Reached end of address list without finding suitable socket address space");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (listen(cfd,BACKLOG)==0){
        printf("Server listening....\n");
    }
    for (;;){
        socklen=sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        afd=accept(cfd,(struct sockaddr*) &claddr,&socklen);
        if (afd==-1){
            perror("Accept failed");
        }
        getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*) &claddr,socklen,
            host,NI_MAXHOST,service,NI_MAXSERV,0);
        snprintf(addrstr,NI_MAXSERV+NI_MAXHOST+10, "Connection received from: (%s, %s)", host,service); 
        printf("%s\n",addrstr);
        reverser_response(afd,write_buff,read_buff);
    
    }
    close(afd);
    close(cfd);
}
```

And this is the server implementation, which sends a message to the server, and then reads through the socket the reversed message the server sends back:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include "server.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "struct.h"

#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 200
void chat_function(int sockfd,char *write_buffer,char *read_buffer){
    printf("\nEnter a message to send to the server. The server will reverse it, and send it back\n");
    fscanf(stdin,"%s",write_buffer);
    int m=strlen(write_buffer);
    write_buffer[m]='\0';
    int i=0;
    if (write(sockfd,write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer))!=0){
        printf("Failed to send message to server\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    read(sockfd,read_buffer,sizeof(read_buffer));
    int j=strlen(read_buffer);
    read_buffer[j]='\0';
    int z=0;
    printf("Reversed server response:\n");
    while (read_buffer[z]!='\0'){
        printf("%c",read_buffer[z]);
        z++;
    }
}



int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int cfd;
    socklen_t socklen;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC; //can accept IPV4 or IPV6
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_next=NULL; 
    hints.ai_canonname=NULL;
    hints.ai_addr=NULL;
    hints.ai_flags=AI_NUMERICSERV;
    char addbuff[NI_MAXSERV+NI_MAXHOST+10];
    char write_buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    char read_buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    bzero(write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer));
    bzero(read_buffer,sizeof(read_buffer));
    if (argc<2){
        printf("Failed to give hostname for client");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    if ((getaddrinfo(argv[1],PORT_NUM,&hints,&result))!=0){
        printf("You did not provide a legitimate host name for the client socket to search through addresses to connect to");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (rp=result;rp;rp=rp->ai_next){
        cfd=socket(rp->ai_family,rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (cfd==-1){
            continue;
        }
        if (connect(cfd,rp->ai_addr,rp->ai_addrlen)!=-1){
            int error = 0;
            socklen_t len = sizeof (error);
            int retval = getsockopt (cfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len);
            if (retval==0){
                printf("Socket successfully connected\n");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    chat_function(cfd,write_buffer,read_buffer);

    if (rp==NULL){
        printf("Could not connect socket to any address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(cfd);
}
```

With the server running as a background process, I attempt to write to the server like so:

```
./client localhost (this connects the client to the socket that lives at localhost, the server)
```

and when I actually execute the client, I get back the error message I have in my code indicating the write through the socket in the client failed. Furthermore, when adding a print statement to the server's reversal method that outputs the length of the string it received as an arugment to reverse, it will be able to identify the string length of the string it received. This further confuses me - if my client is failing to even write through the socket, how is the server able to know the length of the word it's supposed to reverse?

Comment: I see a lot of problems with this code. Not allocating space for, or even filling in, null terminators in dynamically allocated strings. Not using `sizeof` correctly in socket I/O functions. Lack of error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `send()` and `recv()` instead of `write()` and `read()`
and the next problem is these functions most of the time fail when you want to get more than four byte so you need to do something like this:
(you shouldn't send or take all of them at once.

```
// allocate 4 byte memory for Memory2Send
Remained_Data = i;
j = 0
while (Remained_Data > 0){
      if(Remained_Data > 4){
          memcpy(Memory2Send, Memory4Data + j, 4;
          send(Sock, Memory2Send, 4, 0);
          j = j + 4;
          Remained_Data = Remained_Data - 4;
      }
      else if(Remained_Data < 4){
          memcpy(Memory2Send, Memory4Data + j, 4;
          send(Sock, Memory2Send, Remained_Data, 0);
          Remained_Data = 0;
      }
```

try to send 4 bytes every round. you'll get all the data

and for server-side you need to receive 4 bytes every round.

```
// allocate 4 byte memory for Memory4Recv
j = 1;
z = 0;
while (j != 0) {
    bzero(Memory4Recv,4);
    recv(Sock, Memory4Recv, 4, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        Recv_Data[z] = Memory4Recv[i];
        if (Recv_Data[z] == 0x00){
            j = 0;
            break;
            }
        z++;
        }
    }
```

put a null byte at the end of the reserved memory and if the size is equal to `i` send, `i + 1`;

if you want to communicate better, send more than 4 bytes each round and get a more reliable connection, you should do it on kernel-side. but first, get better in C and user-side socket programming then go for kernel-side.

Comment: Great, thanks. I realize now the lack of the null terminator at the end of my strings would mess things up. Out of curiousity, why can't send and recv() or read/write handle sending or receiving more than 4 bytes at a time well?

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein I really don't know! just by experience and checking the values of memory on the client-side and server-side, I figure that out. if you want to send large files about even gigabytes of data, you won't get into trouble with sending 4 bytes each round. it's safer and works perfectly.

Comment: No.  You MUST NOT ignore the results returned from system calls like recv().

Comment: 'these functions most of the time fail when you want to get more than four byte' what???   If you ask for four bytes, you could get one, and that is not a fail.  All TCP stream apps MUST be able to function correctly even if every succesful send() returns 1 and every successful recv() returns 1.

Comment: 'it's safer and works perfectly'   no, it's not safe and it's totally wrong:((

Comment: @MartinJames yes maybe you are right. i checked all possible combinations, amount of data which received, the memory of both sides and lots of other things.```send``` and ```recv``` return the amount data which was sent or received. I remember while working with ```recv``` function. the amount data which was received (according to return value) wasn't the always same number. if you try to send 128 byte, for example, the returned value was various between the range of 5 - 67.

Comment: @MartinJames a null byte at the end can help. maybe "fail" was a bad word for this. but for me ```recv``` doesn't receive all data for long strings. sometimes it was all of them and sometimes it was just the first few bytes of it. which part do you think I made mistake?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230490/discussion-between-askingoverflow-and-martin-james).

Comment: 'which part do you think I made mistake?': 'SOCK_STREAM'.  The only messages are one byte long.  Anything larger needs a protocol on top of TCP.